# Query column based on presence of value in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to find all the rows in a dataframe where the text from one column can be found in a second column. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['THE BIG DANCE', 'BIG'], ['SUPER FUN TIME', 'JUNK'], ['TEST', 'TEST']], columns=list('ab'), dtype="string")
df
```

This produces a dataframe that looks like this:

|  | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | THE BIG DANCE | BIG |
| 1 | SUPER FUN TIME | JUNK |
| 2 | TEST | TEST |

I want to create a new dataframe with row 0 and row 2 because column a in those rows contains text that is in column b.
I tried using the query function but it only returns row 2.

```
df.query('b in a')
```

Returns:

|  | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | TEST | TEST |

The python in operators works correctly with this text but it doesn't seem to be honored by the pandas dataframe.

```
'BIG' in 'THE BIG DANCE'
Returns: True
```

Does anyone know the most efficient way to query a dataframe to find all the rows whos text from one column contains text found in a second column?

Comment: `df[[b in (a) for a,b in zip(df['a'],df['b'])]]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should do the job

```
>>> df[df.apply(lambda x: x['b'] in x['a'], axis=1)]
               a     b
0  THE BIG DANCE   BIG
2           TEST  TEST
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be this:

```
selection = df.apply(lambda x: x[1] in x[0].split(), axis=1)
>>> selection
True
False
True

df[selection]
>>> df
               a     b
0  THE BIG DANCE   BIG
2           TEST  TEST
```